# Verb for sentence joined by comma?

Tags: grammar, tenses

I am writing a novel and this sentence comes in middle of a paragraph.

> When such people found someone who was not easily bored or not greedy, they reacted unexpectedly.

I this sentence, the form of verb for "react" is correct?

How do I decide which tense to use in the part "they reacted unexpectedly"?

Comment: Sorry, and although "When such people found someone who was not easily bored or not greedy, they reacted unexpectedly" might in some circumstances be re-worded to make sense, what you actually Posted will never work in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct, think of it as

> When they found someone, they reacted.

which is a completely valid sentence.

It may be worth trying to rephrase the sentence though, since it is rather dense and difficult to read. Perhaps

> They reacted unexpectedly when they found someone who wasn't easily bored or greedy.

would work. That way you say what they do before saying to whom they do it, and remove the redundant "not".

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I will try to make a simpler sentence.